# Not getting any output with Javascript code

Tags: javascript, for-loop, output, addition

I need some help with this problem.

Exercise:

- Use a for-loop to increment 399 with the value 8, 13 times.

My Code so far.

```
 var a = 399;  
 var b = 8;

 for (i = 0; i < 13; i++) {  
   a += b; 
 }
 ANSWER = a;
```

When I run it I don't get any output.

**What should I do in order to get the output?**

Comment: What's the error?  The code demonstrably works: https://jsfiddle.net/hepjc6k0/

Comment: I dont get any answer at all, thats the error.

Comment: It works ! https://jsfiddle.net/xta39de8/1/

Comment: you didn't print it?

Comment: wait, `ANSWER` is nothing... you can create a variable like done for a and b, or make a console.log(a) instead of ANSWER = a;

Comment: Yep, I think his problem he needs to print it :D

Comment: @oliverBergman: Something else must be wrong.  This code works exactly as expected.  What specifically do you mean by "I don't get any answer"?

Comment: @oliverBergman you must use an output method to see the answer like alert or console log or element.html()

Comment: solved it! thank you, sometimes you just need another pair of eyes ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is fine, and in order to output the result, add this after the `for` loop:

Display in browser console

`console.log(a);`

Display a blocking alert

`alert(a);`

Here's a demo with alert():

```js
var a = 399;
var b = 8;

for (i = 0; i < 13; i++) {  
  a += b; 
}

alert(a); // output it
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `alert()` to create a popup in the browser, or you can use `console.log()` to output to the browser's console.

```js
 var a = 399;  
 var b = 8;

 for (i = 0; i < 13; i++) {  
   a += b; 
 }
alert(a);
console.log(a);
```